# Percorrer array e verificar se um campo está vazio (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, array

Num dos ficheiros tenho uma tabela dinâmica que recebe os dados do `BD`, mas com possibilidade de inserir mais linhas na tabela. De notar que quando insiro mais linhas o `idFaturacao` vai ser vazio.
Esta é a minha tabela:

```
<TABLE id="dataTable">
<?php 
    $query_periodosFaturacao = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM faturacao WHERE fk_obras=$id ORDER BY num_fatura ASC");
    while($periodosFaturacao = mysqli_fetch_array($query_periodosFaturacao)) {
            echo "<TR>";
            echo "<TD width='100px;'><INPUT type='date' id='data_afaturar' name='data_afaturar[]' value='".$periodosFaturacao['data']."' required/></TD>";
            echo "<TD><input type='text' name='valor_afaturar[]' id='valor_afaturar' value='".$periodosFaturacao['valor']."' required>€</TD>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='idFaturacao[]' value='".$periodosFaturacao['id']."' />";
            echo "</TR>";
    }
    ?>
</TABLE>
```

Num outro ficheiro onde faço o envio dos dados para a base de dados, o problema está aqui! Ao percorrer o `array`, os elementos que forem vazios ele faz o `INSERT` e os elementos em que `idFaturacao` está preenchido ele faz o `UPDATE` da info. Eu não sei é como verifico os elementos vazios e preenchidos no array.

```
$data_afaturar = $_POST['data_afaturar'];
$valor_afaturar = $_POST['valor_afaturar'];
$idFaturacao = $_POST['idFaturacao'];

foreach($data_afaturar as $a => $b){
    if(empty($idFaturacao[$a])){
        echo "INSERT";
    }
    else{
        echo "UPDATE";
    }
}
```

Obrigada pela atenção!

Comment: Hora alguma você declarou a variável `$id_faturacao`, isso parece estar errado.

Comment: Francisco a variável foi declarada aqui:
$idFaturacao = $_POST['idFaturacao'];

Comment: Não, não foi. São nomes diferentes, nomes de variáveis devem ser estritamente iguais. [Veja mais aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.php).

Comment: Francisco, tem razão tinha um underscore a mais. De qualquer forma não corrige a situação.

Comment: Vc tem uma variavel $idFaturacao e dentro do foreach vc tem uma outra variavel $idfaturacao com o f minusculo

Comment: Seu código ta muito sem sentido, no foreach você itera sobre o `$data_afaturar` e na verificação, você está checando o `$idFaturação`.

Comment: Francisco no foreach tenho o $data_afaturar porque esse é um elemento que nunca está vazio, por isso quero checar é quando o $idFaturação está!

Comment: Entendi. E o php está alegando algum erro?

Comment: Como está, no HTML, os campos que serão utilizado para inserir novos dados? Na pergunta você colocou apenas as linhas que são geradas para os registros existente. E como o Francisco perguntou, aparece algum erro? Qual?

Comment: Olá não aparece nenhum erro. apenas não faz o que estou a precisar que faça. Que é o array tem vários elementos, mas alguns estão vazios. O que eu preciso é que ele percorra o array e dentro deste, os elementos que tiverem vazio ele faça 'INSERT'  e no array as posições que tiverem dados ele faz o 'UPDATE'. Não sei se me fiz entender bem...
Por exemplo, se o array for assim :'1', '2', '', '4'.
Ele faz o UPDATE do '1', '2' e '4', e no que está vazio '' ele faz um INSERT

Comment: Joana, e como está o HTML deste campo que vem com o `id` vazio? Considerando que o que postou na pergunta é apenas um *loop* dos registros do banco, sempre haverá um `id` associado. Existe algum outro formulário que o usuário pode inserir novos dados?

Answer (score 1):

`Por exemplo, se o array for assim :'1', '2', '', '4'.`    Basta verificar se $b é vazio

[**Teste clicando aqui**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/761dbe0953c080a4c2e16aeaa6a927867bfaab9b)

```
$idFaturacao = array("1", "2", "", "4");

foreach ($idFaturacao as $a => $b) {
    //$b = trim($b);
    if (empty($b))
        echo "indice $a -> $b faz INSERT <br>";
    else
        echo "indice $a -> $b faz UPDATE <br>";
}
```

> Com código da pergunta [**teste aqui**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6db73c821cd62de4c5638d3d1dbd1ac3df1a7da8)

```
$data_afaturar = array("a", "b", "c", "d");
$idFaturacao = array("1", "2", "", "4");


foreach($data_afaturar as $a => $b){
    if(empty($idFaturacao[$a])){
        echo "indice $a -> $b faz INSERT <br>";
    }
    else{
        echo "indice $a -> $b faz UPDATE <br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas não é o valor de `$data_afarurar` que é necessário verificar, mas sim o valor em `$idFaturacao`.

Comment: Por exemplo, se o array for assim :'1', '2', '', '4'.

Comment: Exato. O `$data_afaturar` vem como `["a", "b", "c", "d"]` e o `$idFaturacao` com como `["1", "2", "", "4"]`. O que é preciso fazer é que se o índice em `$iDFaturacao` estiver vazio, faça o *insert* de `$data_afaturar`, mas se tiver um valor, faça o *update* no *id*.

Comment: hummmmm entendi seu entendimento :)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss deu no mesmo http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1382874ed041b42c070337597d182fe39c615cef

Comment: Obrigada. Ficou resolvido!

Comment: Pois é. Você conseguiu ver algum erro no código da pergunta?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss talvez quem sabe tradução do Português de Portugal para Português do Brasil para entender melhor a pergunta! :)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, vendo os comentários do Francisco e a edição da pergunta acho que as correções já haviam sido feitas, portanto mérito do Francisco